# GOOGLE ANALYTICS vs CHROME PLATFORM ANALYTICS vs FIREBASE ANALYTICS for a Chrome Extension with web component plus mobile apps?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics can cover web apps and mobile apps, but is not supported for analytics inside Chrome Web Store. Chrome Platform Analytics seems to be purpose-made for packaged extensions, but I guess won't work for web or mobile components. And then there's good old Google Analytics... hmmm...

1. In general, it better to create a separate analytics property/tag for each separate medium?
2. If so, is the data shared across properties?
3. My Chrome extension has a web component. Should I use one standard Google Analytics tag across both the extension package and web instead of Chrome Platform Analytics? Or would I use Chrome Platform Analytics plus a separate property for the web pages? (note: web used for registration, logging in/out, settings, dashboard)
4. I intend to create the same extension for other browser platforms. Would I use a different Google Analytics property/tag or the same one across all extensions?
5. Mobile apps are not yet developed. Should I use Firebase Analytics for these, or what?

Thanks for your input!